# How to remove duplicated row depending on two different columns in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to delete all the duplicated rows from my data.frame only if their values on another column is different.

Let's say I have a data.frame like this :

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A       -       10
A       -       13
A       -       15
B       -       18
B       -       18
B       -       23
```

The result should be :

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A       -       10
B       -       18
B       -       18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1[ave(df1$Column3, df1$Column1, FUN = function(x) x == x[1]) == 1,]
#  Column1 Column2 Column3
#1       A       -      10
#3       B       -      18
#4       B       -      18
```

Comment: similar to your edit if all columns but one must match: `df[-which(duplicated(df) != duplicated(df$Column1)),]`

Comment: @Andrew, what if there was one more row with `A    -    13`

Comment: Good point! I guess @Arkning could clarify the desired result if the dataframe had another `A - 13` like this: `df <- data.frame(Column1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Column2 = rep("-", Column3 = c(10, 13, 13, 18, stringsAsFactors = F)`. I.e., keep `A10` or the `A13`'s? Or, that may not be relevant depending on how the data is setup.

Comment: Yes if there are many rows it should delete them if the value inside the Column3 isn't the same. I've edited my example so it's more clear